# Latex: splitting/processing strings inside a latex command

Tags: strings, xstring

Let's say I have

```
\ingredients
{%
    \unit[375]{g} & Farina 00\\
    \unit[250]{g} & Burro\\
    \unit[3]{g} & Sale\\
    1 & Limone
}
```

(you got me: I'm dealing with xcookybooky)
and I want to write a new command

```
\myIngredients
{%
    \unit[375]{g} & Farina 00\\
    \unit[250]{g} & Burro\\
    \unit[3]{g} & Sale\\
    1 & Limone
}
```

so that I obtain

```
\ingredients
{%
    \unit[375]{g} & \Index{Farina 00}\\
    \unit[250]{g} & \Index{Burro}\\
    \unit[3]{g} & \Index{Sale}\\
    1 & \Index{Limone}
}
```

What is the best way to do it using Latex (no pure Tex as possible, please)?
I looked at xstring and stringstring but I did not find anything useful.

I am able and willing to use regexp too, but, again I did not find anything suitable.

Any help in form of literature or link to generic way of splitting and processing complex strings using latex would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: the underlying \ingredients command is defined as

```
\newcommand*{\ingredients}[1]
{%
\def\xcb@ingredients
{%
 \vspace{-1em} % same height of ingredients and preparation
 \xcb@name@inghead
 %\\[4pt]
 \\[1em]
 \xcb@fontsize@ing\color{\xcb@color@ing}
 \begin{tabularx}{\xcb@ingredientswidth}{rX}
     ##1
 \end{tabularx}
 }
}
```

Comment: You could split the input token list as you suggest but it is probably simpler and more robust simply to modify the definition of \ingredients, adding the `\Index` command to the underlying \begin{tabular} setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am afraid I did not understand what you mean, I edited my original post to show the underlying \ingredients command, but its arguments is passed straight away to  tabularx as I can see, so it is just what I want to do ... or am I missing something?

Comment: It would help if you provide a minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It always helps to post _complete_ documents that can be run (so people can test their answers) rather than fragments but you could just use `>{\addindex}X<{\\}` where `\addindex` is something like `\def\addindex#1\\{\Index{#1}\\}` (or somewhere there is a latex package to add commands around table cells rather than using `\def`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can examine the items one by one and emit the suitable `\index` command *before* the table is compiled.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % just for the example

\usepackage{tabularx,imakeidx,siunitx}

\makeindex

% a provisional definition of \ingredients, just for the example    
\newcommand*{\ingredients}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
  #1
  \end{tabularx}
  \par\bigskip
}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ingredientsidx}{m}
 {
  \massi_ingredients:n { #1 } % this makes the index entries
  \ingredients { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_massi_ingredients_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_massi_ingredients_onerow_seq
\tl_new:N \l_massi_ingredients_item_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \massi_ingredients:n #1
 {
  % split the input line by line
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_massi_ingredients_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % get each ingredient
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_massi_ingredients_rows_seq
   {
    % split at &
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_massi_ingredients_onerow_seq { & } { ##1 }
    % get the second item in the sequence, removing spaces on either side
    \tl_set:Nx \l_massi_ingredients_item_tl
     {
      \exp_not:N \index { \tl_trim_spaces:f { \seq_item:Nn \l_massi_ingredients_onerow_seq { 2 } } }
     }
    % now use the item (already set in an \index entry)
    \tl_use:N \l_massi_ingredients_item_tl
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_trim_spaces:n { f }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ingredientsidx{
  \SI{375}{g} & Farina 00\\
  \SI{250}{g} & Burro\\
  \SI{3}{g} & Sale\\
  1 & Limone
}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use older packages for units: with `siunitx` you have many bell and whistles.

Comment: I didn't understand the solution, but it worked, even if I forgot to mention that \ingredients is a command defined inside the \recipe environment, so many thanks.
I'll use siunitx now, I did not know it, I sticked with what was used and suggested in xcookybooky package.

Comment: @massi I just provided an `\ingredients` macro in order not to load `cookybooky` and study its quirks. The definition is just a poor man's version of it.

Comment: :) That one is the only thing I understood, I just can't catch up with code. I am decent in Latex, but I do know almost nothing about Tex

Comment: @massi That's LaTeX3.

Comment: :O I did not have the least idea of its existence until your reply, so
1. wow, the first answer is from THAT carlisle I suppose
2. where can I find documentation about it, since http://latex-project.org/latex3.html does not seem to say a lot and I'm definitely eager to use itù